# Check and uncheck inputs work only one time with Jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am trying to check/uncheck all checkboxes by click on one checkbox in head of table. First click add attribute to inputs, second uncheck. It works only one time. Testing on Firefox and Chrome.
Аttributes keep changing, but this is not shown in page. I see it only in browser debugger.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
            <th>#</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('th input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if ( $(this).is(':checked') )
            $('td input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
        else
            // $('td input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', false);
            $('td input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
    })
});
</script>
```

Sample
http://jsfiddle.net/aJhm9/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use properties instead of attributes

```
$(function () {
    $('th input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if ( $(this).is(':checked') )
            $('td input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
        else
            $('td input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aJhm9/2/

Comment: It works, thanks! but attr() worked every time... why not now?

Answer (score 3):

`.attr()` is for modifying an elements default state only, not its live state Use `.prop()` for changing the live state of an element.

Answer (score 0):

use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr()`

```
 $(function () {
   $('th input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') )
        $('td input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
    else
        $('td input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
   })
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/aJhm9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Why use jQuery for such a small task? Just set the ID of the main checkbox at the head of your table to a unique name. Then add a specific class to all your other checkboxes in the table. Then use the following code: -

```
var mainCheckbox = document.getElementById('name_of_ID');

if(window.addEventListener) {
    mainCheckbox.addEventListener('change', togglecheckboxes, false);
} else {
    mainCheckbox.attachEvent('onchange', togglecheckboxes);
}

function togglecheckboxes(){
    var otherCheckboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('name_of_CLASS'); //returns an array
        for(var i = 0; i < otherCheckboxes.length; i++){
            otherCheckboxes[i].checked = mainCheckbox.checked;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $('#select_all').click(function () {
    $( this ).closest('form').find(':checkbox').prop( 'checked' , this.checked ? true : false );
})
</script>
```